# How much memory can be saved on making all the icon pics required on putting in a png format?

Tags: css, image, png, loading

Sites like facebook,google plus have there whole images in one picture how many bytes of memory
can be saved using this method

[image]

[image]

Comment: You'll probably save around 78 bytes of memory using this method. Good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called `CSS Image Spriting` through this we can save our HTTP Requests to server.
If we will use this method so our one HTTP request will go to server and call all the required images through `CSS Image Spriting`.
So now most of us are using this method :

read more about the [`CSS Image Spriting`](http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/)

Answer (score 9):

You are not saving any memory. You are saving bandwidth because you are making fewer HTTP requests to the server.

As pointed out by `@iccthedral` in the comments section you are actually saving bytes because you now have a single image => the total amount of saved bytes = `numberOfPictures * sizeof(pngHeader)`.

Comment: It saves a bit. numOfPics * sizeof(pngHeader) roughly

Comment: @iccthedral, good point. I will update my answer to include it.

Comment: It's 8 bytes long. 
So, savedBytes ~ numOfPics * 8 + C, where C would be some small dependent value >= 0. You would have to test it to find out I guess.

Comment: Further, if the images have palette, the saved bits would be far greater (but perhaps many pics would require more colors in the palette, so it's not trivial). In any case, these saved bits are not the point, the point is having less http requests.

Comment: And 8 bytes is only the PNG signature, you should add the IHDR and END chunks (12+13+12=37 bytes)

Answer (score 1):

Those images are called [CSS image sprites](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_sprites.asp). 
They are used to minimise server requests, rather to save memory.

Also You might consider using SVG icons, which weight slightly more, but can efficiently used to save space if You need the same icon in different sizes. Here is a good material to read : [Resolution Independence With SVG](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2012/01/16/resolution-independence-with-svg/)

Answer (score 1):

its not the question how much memory gets saved, its how many http requests your "**not doing**" by having your images in to a sprite. Site will load faster

The amount of kb on images will +- stay the same, individual or sprited